# Definition of "registrar" and "author" accounts?

Tags: accounts

What do these accounts refer to in ethereum?  Particularly when setting up a private blockchain?

Comment: Please include more context.  I would guess that "author" accounts are those that are allowed to create blocks (like in a Proof of Authority blockchain), and a "registrar" is way to look up which accounts are authors, and possibly other information about authors.

Comment: Thank you but the point of the question is to get a general definition of the way these terms are used instead of specific context.  The reason is because the individual ways they come up don't seem to be all the same (to me) and that is why I'm asking the question.  What would be very helpful is if you could explain what you just wrote.  for example: *how* does the registrar look up an account and what does it mean to look up an account?

Comment: Here are some references which may help someone (or yourself) write an answer: PoA https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225 and ENS for registrars https://github.com/ethereum/ens

Comment: What?  Those definitely don't relate to my question.  PoA?  What are you talking about?  My question has nothing to do with that.  Also my question has nothing to do with the ENS.  Both of those terms pre-date both of those concepts by a long time (in ethereum time at least)